# Why does XmlDocument.LoadXml throw System.Net.WebException?

Tags: .net, xml, vb.net, exception, xmldocument

Why does `System.Xml.XmlDocument.LoadXml` method throw `System.Net.WebException` ?

This is really mind boggling crazy, if [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.loadxml.aspx) was right, `LoadXml` should at most give me a `System.Xml.XmlException`.

Yet I have weird exceptions like:

> The underlying connection was closed: The connection was closed unexpectedly.

```
Dim document As New XmlDocument
document.LoadXml("<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC ""-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"" ""http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd""><x></x>")
MsgBox(document.LastChild.Name)
```

What on earth is causing the exception ?

Comment: **[TL;DR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Too_long;_didn%27t_read)**... Try to find the source of this problem yourself by gradually reducing the XML until the problem disappears. After that update your question with a concise example.

Comment: I am assuming that the DOCTYPE declaration is being resolved, as it will work without error if the DOCTYPE is removed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Edwin gave you the solution, and I'm giving you the reason for the connection drop:

http://www.w3.org/blog/systeam/2008/02/08/w3c_s_excessive_dtd_traffic/

Answer (score 10):

The internal XmlReader of a XmlDocument uses a XmlResolver to load external resources. You should prevent the opening of the DTD by setting the `XmlResolver` to null and setting `DtdProcessing` to ignore. This can be done by applying a `XmlReaderSettings` object to a new `XmlReader`. This reader can then be used to load the XML into the XmlDocument. That should solve your issue.

```
    Dim doc As New XmlDocument()
    Dim settings As New XmlReaderSettings()
    settings.XmlResolver = Nothing
    settings.DtdProcessing = DtdProcessing.Ignore

    Using sr As New StringReader("<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC ""-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"" ""http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd""><x></x>")
        Using reader As XmlReader = XmlReader.Create(sr, settings)
            doc.Load(reader)
        End Using
    End Using
```

Comment: This can also be done by setting the XmlResolver property of the XmlDocument to Nothing, before calling Load() or LoadXml().